# Sending notificationCallback from PHP to AngularJS's $http

Tags: php, angularjs, http, callback, promise

I'm using AngularJS to retrieve and post a file to a PHP script, which later does some mambojumbo taking a few seconds to finally report success or error.
Is there any chance that PHP can send Angular Promises' notificationCallback so I can inform the user what's going on?

Comment: [The HTTP standard](http://w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) certainly allows for multiple 1xx series "Informational" responses prior to a final 2xx,3xx,4xx or 5xx. I've never needed to do this so no idea what you would write server-side or client-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked around this. I had to use a different approach to inform my web application about the status of the running PHP script at the backend.

Instead of using **Angular's $http** functions, I switched to [**Oboe.js**](http://oboejs.com) for this particular call.

In order to do so in my setup, I used [RonB's angular-oboe implementation](https://github.com/RonB/angular-oboe) and [Makeroni's PHP Oboe.js implementation example](https://github.com/Makeroni/JSON-Streaming-Javascript) to kickstart my actual process.